# SQL query using 'Group By' and 'WHERE' return all values with 0 count if they have no data

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

i have a table named LOG, in this table i have a column named Level and has 3 possibles values: 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR'.

I want to take the count of each of this values, so my query is

```
SELECT Level, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM LOG GROUP BY Level
```

The result i get is something to 'ERROR': X, 'INFO': Y, 'WARN': Z.

I have and second column named 'Logger' that can take a lot of values, for example 'Upload Data'. Now i want to add WHERE condition only for Logger='Upload Data'

```
SELECT Level, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM LOG WHERE Logger='Upload Data' GROUP BY Level
```

Now the result i get is something to 'ERROR': X, 'INFO': Y.

*'WARN' missing*

and this is my problem.

How can modified this query to return this structure
'ERROR': X, 'INFO': Y, 'WARN': **0**.

if has no data?

Comment: post your table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Level, SUM(`Count`) AS `Count`
FROM (
    SELECT Level, COUNT(*) AS `Count` FROM LOG WHERE Logger='Upload Data' GROUP BY Level
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Level, 0 AS `Count` FROM LOG GROUP BY Level
) t
GROUP BY Level
```

Comment: This has a risk of having the original problem, if the entire log table has not a single instance of a perticular level. Specifically, if the entire log table has zero rows, it will output zero rows and not the expected three rows having zero counts. I suggest creating a seperate  table for Levels or taking three union-all for three log levels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
  Level,
  COUNT(IF(Logger='Upload Data', Logger, NULL)) AS COUNT
FROM LOG
GROUP BY Level
```

Comment: Please show your result query. Here it is an IF function - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if